# Instead of using a hard coded values in JavaScript, is it possible to use a cron to do it?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, cron, dynamic-forms

It's probably easiest to understand by looking at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TdBdW/1/ - apologies for the lack of css.

As you can see, for my dynamically generated dropdowns and textboxes I have a big list of hardcoded values. I would have liked to have pulled these straight from a database but the queries take too long to run for them to be used in real-time - i.e. when the user clicks on a drop-down or tries to type in the auto-complete box.

Instead what I would like to do is have the relevant queries run nightly using a cron job but the question is how to take the results of the query and put them into my javascript file.

Anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Martin

Comment: Your drop down list appear to be small. You probably have design or optimisation  issues. I making autocomplete and drop down list on thousands of items without problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best route to achieve what you want ("cron job creates data for use by javascript") is to go via JSON. This involves:

1. Create a cron job that a) fetches the data, and b) writes it to a file formatted using JSON conventions which is accessible from your web server,
2. Amend your html to include the file created by the cron job.

For simplicity you could create the javascript file using contents similar to the following:

```
var agentValues = [
        "excel",
        "msword",
        "ppt",
];
```

You can easily create this with a static first and last line, and simply add the quoted values from your query in between. You can then load this file into your html document like any other javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

When you populate the autocomplete values, simply use a `for` loop over this array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++) {
    $("<option>" + agentValues[i] + "</option>").appendTo($values);
}
```

The above would be the most basic version of achieving your aims, and you can improve on it, e.g. by:

1. Adding error checking
2. Structuring your namespace so that you don't have many top-level variables
3. Adding the data values to your existing javascript, rather than a separate file
4. etc.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, do you mind if I ask a few questions? Basically, the query will be the same except the tag we are searching for will change - i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT value FROM documenttags WHERE tag = 'agent' GROUP BY value`. I am thinking if it's better to run the query in a loop using a variable for all the different tags? Then I was also wondering how to encode it as JSON - I know there is a PHP function but I also found this: http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html

Comment: Yes, looping over the mysql query is fine - you can still put everything into a single javascript file, you just need a first and last line (as above) for each group, with a different var name. If you are absolutely certain that your values will only contain letters, you don't need a fancy JSON encoding routine - just enclose the value in quotes, and add a comma at the end (because in a JSON array, multiple values need to be separated by commas). JSON may sound tricky, but its simply the javascript you would write to set the value in your javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to optimize your queries? If you run a cron job, I suppose you could write the results to a json or xml file on the server and pull that file using XHR (aka AJAX).

Alternatively you can design/create a table in the database containing the results of the cronned query, and pull your data from that table?

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want your javascript file to be static. Why not have it dynamically generated by a php script in the same way that html is generated? If it's easier you could just inline the javascript in your html as opposed to loading it as a separate asset.

If you're worried about hitting the db each time for the tag list, you could instead keep your tags in some global object, which is periodically updated.